# How to search for a text between two patterns in one line with multiple occurrences using sed?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a file like:

"This is a sample file to find text between p1 ***(the first pattern) and*** p2 (the second pattern) in one line, where we can have multiple occurrences of p1 ***followed by*** p2 and I only want the text between p1 ***and*** p2 in the same line."

I want to print the output like the following:
 ***(the first pattern) and  followed by  and***

I try the command

`cat filename | sed -e 's/.*p1\(.*\)p2.*/\1/g'`

but it only prints out the last one like:
 ***and***

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have GNU `grep` you can use perl compatible regular expressions:

```
grep -oP 'p1\K.+?(?=p2)' filename
```

Explanation:

- `\K` resets the match after `p1` has been matched. That would prevent `p1` from getting included into the match result.
- `.+?` matches one or more arbitrary characters - *ungreedy*, meaning only until the nearest occurrence of `p2`
- `(?=p2)` is a lookahead assertion. It means that the previous pattern, which was `.+?` needs to get followed by `p2`.

Comment: thank you so much for the answer, you saved my day :)

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have GNU grep, you should be able to tweak your `sed` expression to accomplish what you need, for example:

```
sed 's/^.*p1\(..*\)p2.*$/\1/'
```

which is essentially what you have aside from the additional `'.'` that insures there is a least 1 char between `p1` and `p2` that can be output via the backreference. In this case, it is limited to 1-occurrence of `p1` and `p2` in each line. The `'g'` for a global replace would be superfluous.

**Example**

If `p1` is `code` and `p2` is `endcode` and `111_000` is the wanted text, you could do the following:

```
$ printf "A line with a code111_000endcode and stuff\n" | 
sed 's/^.*code\(..*\)endcode.*$/\1/'
111_000
```

If you have GNU grep, go that route, if not, give this a shot.

Comment: The problem here is that this would not work with lines which contain multiple of those patterns like `p1foop2p1barp2`

Comment: That's true, that's why I noted that it was limited to `1-occurrence` of pattern1/pattern2 in the line.